# Corruption when array doesn't overflow

Tags: c++, arrays, corruption

I'm getting corruption of `Q_List[2].Status`, which was Present, and after the for loops it corrupts to Edge. I had set up before as a normal enum, and the corrupted value as an int came out as 256. Change it to enum class and I still get a problem. I can't see how it's overflowing the array as it doesn't go past 2 on the bounds in the for loops and I've set it up as 2+1, but if I change it to:

```
bool Available[Max_Energy + 2][Max_Energy + 2][...
```

then it doesn't corrupt, so it's something like that.

#### Main.cpp

```
Q_List[Current_Q].Fill_Available_Fns_Array(Q_List[Adjacent_Q_ID], Right, &Q_List[2]);
```

#### Q.h

```
bool Available[Max_Energy + 1][Max_Energy + 1][Right][Longest_Range + 1];

status Get_Status() { // Transcendent returns 
    //scriptfile << "Call Get_Status() = " << Status << ".\n";
    if (Status == status::Present) {
        return Status;
    }
    else if (Status == status::Transcendent){
        return Status;
    }
    else if (Status == status::Edge){
        return Status;
    }
    else
    {
        return status::Edge;
    }
};

void Fill_Available_Fns_Array(Quanta Second_Q, Handed Side, Quanta * Debug) {
    Second_Q_Effective_Energy = Max_Energy;
    scriptfile << "Here???? this = " << this << " with energy = " << (*this).Get_Energy() << "\n";
    for (Q_energy_count = 1; Q_energy_count <= (*this).Get_Energy(); Q_energy_count++){
        for (Second_Q_energy_count = 1; Second_Q_energy_count <= Second_Q_Effective_Energy; Second_Q_energy_count++){
            for (Slot_C = 1; Slot_C <= Longest_Range; Slot_C++){
                scriptfile << "X" << Q_energy_count << Second_Q_energy_count << Side << Slot_C;
                Available[Q_energy_count][Second_Q_energy_count][Side][Slot_C] = true;
                if ((*Debug).Get_Status() == status::Edge)
                {
                    scriptfile << "E\n";
                }
                else if ((*Debug).Get_Status() == status::Present)
                {
                    scriptfile << "P\n";
                }
                else if ((*Debug).Get_Status() == status::Transcendent)
                {
                    scriptfile << "T\n";
                }
                else
                    scriptfile << "?\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

#### I.h

```
enum class status { Edge, Present, Transcendent };
enum Handed { Left = 1, Right };
const int Longest_Range = 1;
const int Max_Energy = 2;
```

#### Output to scriptfile

```
Here???? this = 00059610 with energy = 2
X1121P
X1221P
X2121P
X2221E
```

Comment: You're writing out of bounds, or other [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? Start by using a memory debugger (for example something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). Also, what is `Q_List`? How is it declared, defined and initialized?

Comment: In C++ array indices are from 0 to (size-1).  You appear to be using 1 to size.  You probably want `Q_energy_count = 0; Q_energy_count < Get_Energy()`.

Comment: I'm using 1 to size as it makes the code more readable, not using the 0th element.

Quanta Q_List[10]; // I don't get past using the 3rd one before it goes wrong but they're all initialised using a constructor which sets everything to sensible values.

I haven't set up anything in Visual Studio specially. Do I need to make sure the stack is big enough or anything like that? If not I'll get onto Valgrind, thanks.